# Dell Inspiron 7591 charger ony works at certain angles

Tags: laptop, charger

My original Dell charger got badly damaged, so i bought a new one a couple days ago. It worked fine, but then this morning when i woke up, I noticed the little pin inside the charger was tilted to the side. So I watched a youtube video on how to move it. I got a toothpick and somehow managed to get it back to seemingly the middle. Now it charges, but only when the cord is rotated correctly. This is kind of annoying, so i'd really appreaciate an answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the socket.

You can try bending the pin closer to the spring clip at the side, but you risk breaking it.

[image]

Comment: Also you may need to check if all connections inside are still _tight_.

Comment: Why is it a problem with the socket?

Comment: Isn't that where the pin is? It's unusual to have a pin on a power jack.  If it's not a standard barrel jack post pictures, don't make us guess.